# Poincare inequality for martingales

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

This is a vague question but here we go: Is there a form of the Poincaré inequality that is better suited for martingales?

For example, the Poincaré inequality for the boolean cube states that for any function $f:\{-1,1\}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we have $$Var(f(\epsilon)) \le \mathbb{E} \|Df(\epsilon)\|_2^2,$$ where  we use the uniform measure in the cube and define the partial derivative vector $D f(\epsilon)$ via $$D_i f(\epsilon) = \frac{f(\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_i,\ldots, \epsilon_n) - f(\epsilon_1, \ldots, -\epsilon_i,\ldots, \epsilon_n)}{2},$$ i.e., flipping just the $i$th bit.

Now suppose that $(M_i)_i$ is a martingale adapted to the sequence $\epsilon_1,\ldots, \epsilon_n$ (uniform in the cube) and we are interested in the variance of $g(M_n)$. While this is a function of $\epsilon$ and we can apply the Poincaré inequality, the discrete derivative above does not seem to be appropriate quantity to bound the variance.

Concretely, the Poincaré inequality gives the right bound for linear functions: $$Var\Big(\sum_i a_i \epsilon_i\Big) \le \|a\|_2^2.$$ But consider a Paley-Walsh martingale $$M_n = \sum_{i \le n} V_i \epsilon_i,$$ where $V_i$ is a function of $\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_{i-1}$. While by orthogonality we have a similar expression as above $$Var(M_n) = \sum_i \mathbb{E}(V^2_i),$$ this does not seem to be captured by applying the above Poincaré inequality with $f = M_n$ (notice $D_i M_n$ is not $V_i \epsilon_i$ because flipping $\epsilon_i$ may change $V_{i+1}, \ldots$).

The problem seems to be that in the martingale case changing one bit changes the whole future of the martingale difference sequence; this makes the discrete gradient $D M_n$ too big compared to the actual size of the increments of the martingale.

Any pointers on what is the right way of looking at this are appreciated!

Comment: My intuition is that the Poincaré inequality is just not very sharp; it's based on the crude idea of bounding a matrix below by its (second) smallest eigenvalue.  The right analogy may be an inequality of a different type, though I don't see off the top of my head what the right one is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Nate. You are totally right that such eigenvalue bound for the generator of this process seems inefficient for martingale-looking functions, but maybe there is another diffusion process that is more aware of the filtration (e.g. first continuously change $\epsilon_n$ to a fresh $\epsilon'_n$, and then move to $\epsilon_{n-1}$, etc). That would be a nice mix of the Lindeberg- and Markov semigroup-type interpolations.

Comment: I think the knowledge that $(M_i)$ is a martingale is not particularly helpful as far as the variance of an arbitrary nonlinear function of $M_n$ is a concerned.